# index was outside bounds of array in SSRS when parameter come as blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am working on `SSRS report` where `user!userid` variable coming with `3 pipe delimited values`

E.g :

```
ReportUser |500|100
```

I split the values using below expression

```
=(Split(Parameters!QueryString.Value, "|")).GetValue(0)
=(Split(Parameters!QueryString.Value, "|")).GetValue(1)
=(Split(Parameters!QueryString.Value, "|")).GetValue(2)
```

When the `parameter` is coming with values  above expression works fine. But, when any parameter coming as `blank`, I am getting below below error during `report execution`.

> index was outside bounds of array for the parameter.

I tried below workarounds with iif expression

```
=iif((Split(Parameters!QueryString.Value, "|")).GetValue(0)=NOTHING,0,
      (Split(Parameters!QueryString.Value, "|")).GetValue(0))

=iif((Split(Parameters!QueryString.Value, "|")).GetValue(0)="",0,
      (Split(Parameters!QueryString.Value, "|")).GetValue(0))
```

Still I am getting the same error. Could someone help how to handle the `blank values` with this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had initially though that this would work

**This code fails**

```
=SWITCH
(
Split(Parameters!QueryString.Value, "|").Length <3, "",
True, Split(Parameters!QueryString.Value, "|").GetValue(1)
)
```

As Switch stops evaluating at the first True result but for some reason I still got an Error. I'm not sure why this happens but I got round it by writing a function to do the work.

**This does work**

I added this code to the Reports `Code` property (it can probably be made better but I've not done any VB.Net for years)

```
Public Function GetSplitValue(inputString as String, delim as string, index as Integer) as String

    Dim arr() AS String = Split(inputString, delim)
    Dim result AS string

    TRY
        result = arr(index)
    CATCH
        result = ""
    END TRY

    RETURN result

End Function
```

You can then call this in your expression using something like this in your text boxes or whatever you are populating.

```
=Code.GetSplitValue(Parameters!QueryString.Value,"|",0)
=Code.GetSplitValue(Parameters!QueryString.Value,"|",1)
=Code.GetSplitValue(Parameters!QueryString.Value,"|",2)
```

If you want something other than an empty string, just edit the code in the `CATCH` block.